# Load cache files from a specific Path in osmnx

Tags: python, networkx, osmnx

I have a simple question, is it possible when doing `ox.graph_from_place()` to state where the cache file is. I ran a code on the Ubunu terminal and so I have the cache file in a specific place, now I am running the same code on jupyter lab and I would like to know if I can state where to get the cache from instead of downloading it again.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `cache_folder` parameter in the `ox.config()` function. See [the docs](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.utils.config).

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, cache_folder='./my_cache_folder')
```

Comment: I didn't use it before because in the docs it says "where to save HTTP response cache". I already have them saved, I just want to access them through a path instead of downloading them again. Is cache_folder still applicable in this case?

Comment: Yes. I recently improved the docstring to make that clearer. It'll appear in the next release.